# How to check if style ID contains certain css selectors?

Tags: css, styles

I have the following code in a php file used for theme options:

```
<style type="text/css" id="compiled_styles">
menu {color: red;}
</style>
```

How to check if the style with the ID "compiled_styles" contains certain css selectors?

Basically, I need if that style does not contain any css selector, not to display an unnecessary empty code like this:

```
<style type="text/css" id="compiled_styles">

</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I think you mean about the existing of some ***CSS rule*** in some style, not just selector. You can try this:

```
var style = document.querySelector('#compiled_styles');
var ss = style.sheet || style.styleSheet;
var hasSomeRule = (ss.rules || ss.cssRules).length;
//remove the style if it's empty
if(!hasSomeRule) (style.parentNode || style.parentElement).removeChild(style);
```

### [Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/M6SM2/8/)

Another solution is just try getting some text of the style element, if it's not empty it should have some certain rule:

```
var style = document.querySelector('#compiled_styles');
var hasSomeRule = style.innerHTML.replace(/^\s+$/,'').length;
//remove the style if it's empty
if(!hasSomeRule) (style.parentNode || style.parentElement).removeChild(style);
```

### [Demo 2.](http://jsfiddle.net/viphalongpro/M6SM2/10/)

Comment: Thanks but I don't need an alert, I need that empty style code to not be displayed if contain no rules. Any suggestion? Thank you.

Comment: @Alexan style code should not be rendered, do you mean you want to remove it from the HTML code?

Comment: Yes, I need to be removed from the HTML code. Thanks. Sorry if I was not clear enough.

Comment: I accepted the answer since your code works in demo but not in my Wordpress theme. Maybe it's a stupid question: where and how should I put this javascript code? Is it ok to put it in the theme js file? Thanks.

Comment: @Alexan yes, if you put it in some js file, you should put the `<script></script>` including the js file **at the end** of your HTML code to ensure all the DOM has been loaded. Otherwise (put at the top) you have to place the code in `window.onload = function() { ... }`.